# Why won't the text show up with this code?

Tags: javascript

This is all of the code for an app I've been making for class thats meant to tell you what game to buy depending on the genre, length, and amount of players but I cant figure out why it wont display the text.

It may be obvious whats wrong but this class is my first time coding except so ill miss some obvious things

```
var Genre = getText("genreSelector");

var Length = getNumber("lengthSelector");

var Mode = getText("modeSelector");

onEvent("genreSelector", "change", function( ) {
  updateScreen();
});

onEvent("modeSelector", "change", function( ) {
  updateScreen();
});

onEvent("lengthSelector", "change", function( ) {
  updateScreen();
});

function updateScreen() {
  if (Genre == "RPG" && Mode == "Multiplayer" && Length == 80 || Length == 70 || Length == 60 || Length == 50) {
   setText("selectedGameText", "Baldur's Gate");
  }
  if (Genre == "RPG" && Mode == "Multiplayer" && Length == 40 || Length == 30) {
    setText("selectedGameText", "Diablo");
  }
  if(Genre == "RPG" && Mode == "Multiplayer" && Length == 20 || Length == 10) {
    setText("selectedGameText", "Child of light");
  }
  if (Genre == "RPG" && Mode == "Singleplayer" && Length == 80 || Length == 70 || Length == 60 || Length == 50) {
    setText("selectedGameText", "Final Fantasy");
  }
  if (Genre == "RPG" && Mode == "Singleplayer" && Length == 30 || Length == 20 || Length == 10) {
    setText("selectedGameText", "NieR");
  }
  if (Genre == "Sci-Fi" && Mode == "Multiplayer" && Length == 80 || Length == 70 || Length == 60 || Length == 50) {
    setText("selectedGameText", "Astroneer");
  }
  if (Genre == "Sci-Fi" && Mode == "Multiplayer" && Length == 40 || Length == 30 || Length == 20) {
    setText("selectedGameText", "Destiny 2");
  }
  if (Genre == "Sci-fi" && Mode == "Multiplayer" && Length == 10) {
    setText("selectedGameText", "Halo");
  }
  if (Genre == "Sci-Fi" && Mode == "Singleplayer" && Length == 80 || Length == 70 || Length == 60) {
    setText("selectedGameText", "Mass Effect Legendary Edition");
  }
  if (Genre == "Sci-Fi" && Mode == "Singleplayer" && Length == 40 || Length == 30 ) {
    setText("selectedGameText", "Xcom");
  }
if (Genre == "Sci-Fi" && Mode == "Singleplayer" && Length == 20 || Length == 10) {
    setText("selectedGameText", "Deadspace");
  }
}
```

Comment: Where is `setText` hook?

Comment: Try adding `console.log(Genre, Mode)` at the start of the function to make sure these exactly match the expected values. Are there any errors in the console? Also, you're mixing ands and ors; you should add parentheses around the Length conditions (Note that `false && false || true` gives `true`)

Comment: Unable to help, provide us much data(code, explanation) so we can get exactly what's  wrong.

Comment: Put an `else` in your `updateScreen()` - maybe no game is recommended in your case? `else { setText("selectedGameText", "(none)"); }`. Your browser has built-in debugging tools. You could set a breakpoint and look at the execution line-by-line or add `console.log` calls. Also: With `... && Length == 40 || Length == 30` you probably mean `... && Length <= 40 && Length >= 30`